# Rewrite Custom JavaScript

Tags: magento2.3

I am working at this tutorial in order to rewrite custom JavaScript

in my projet I have included in theses locations :

app/code/Magestore/CustomWidget/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid.js

```
... empty file  ...
```

app/code/Magestore/CustomWidget/view/adminhtml/web/js/requirejs.js

```
(function(require){
    (function() {
        var config = {
            map: {
                '*': {
                    'Grid': Magestore_CustomWidget/js/grid,

                    'mage/adminhtml/grid':Magestore_CustomWidget/js/grid

                }

            }

        };

        require.config(config);

    })();

})(require);
```

app/code/Magestore/CustomWidget/view/frontend/web/js/testJQ.js

```
console.log('here grid custom widget module');

define([
    "jquery"
],
function($) {
    "use strict";
    // Here your custom code...
    console.log('Hola');

    console.log("My name is "+$(".nom").html())

});
```

But when I open the home page and check the console I found nothing , anyone has an idea about that , this is from a tutorial but I don't have any idea about the rules concerning external links in order to post it .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want to do, but if you want to add your js in module and see your `console.log` output in front, here is a solution :

## Module solution :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'Vendor_module/js/myfile',
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           console.log("Holaaaaa.");
       }
});
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`